# jquery apply img src to another img tag in repeater

Tags: jquery, html, image

I am working with an rss feed, and I am using a asp:repeater to show the retrieved data. My issue is I know how to retrieve the image source using jquery that is found in the  tags but my question is - How to apply the retrieved  src to another  tag in a another  control in the same row of the repeater where i retrieved the image src. for .each function can get all the img src, but how to apply them to another img tag in the same row. I need to do this for the sake of changing the displayed data formating.

example:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" OnItemDataBound="R1_ItemDataBound" ><ItemTemplate>

      <table style="width: 100%; height:300px; margin:auto 0px auto 0px ">
              <tr>
                  <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left">
                  <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' Font-Names="BebasNeue-webfont" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#333333"></asp:Label><br/>
                  <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CreatedDate") %>' ForeColor="#CCCCCC" Font-Size="XX-Small"></asp:Label>  


    <!-- Place the retrieved image src from label91 to this img tag -->              
    <img> class="new-image" src="from Label91 retrieved src fom img tag" alt="" </img>
```

```
                  <td style="padding: 5px;  text-align: left; vertical-align: text-top;">
                      <img alt="" src='<%#Eval("BlogId") %>' /> <br/>
<!-- Retrieve image src from the img tag in side the html label91 text to this img tag -->
                  <asp:Label ID="Label91"  runat="server"  Text='<%#Eval("Clip") %>'  Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#666666"></asp:Label>
                       <br/>
                       <asp:Linkbutton ID="more" CssClass="btn btn-sm"  runat="server" PostBackUrl='<%#"ArticleDetails.aspx?id=" + Eval("BlogId") + "&creator=" + Eval("userid") %>'  BackColor="#333399" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Size="X-Small" ForeColor="White">... ler mais </asp:Linkbutton>

                  </td>

              </tr>

          </table>
                   </div>

      </ItemTemplate></asp:Repeater>
```

This is just one code snippet I can't format it to stick together any help will be appriciated on myabove mentioned problem.

Comment: For starters, JavaScript operates on the client-side HTML, not the server-side ASP.NET markup.  You're going to want to take a look at the actual HTML.

Comment: @David when the repeater is rendered all the text in Label91 is render as html, that is when i use jquery to retrieve the <img> tag src ... of the text in the label... I am i wrong?

Comment: Well, when the repeater is rendered then *all* of this will render as HTML.  JavaScript code runs in the browser and knows nothing of the server-side markup that you're looking at.  It only sees the client-side HTML markup.  So if you want to read and modify that HTML with your JavaScript code, the *first* thing you'll need to do is examine that HTML to see what you're working with.  Don't just look at the server-side code and *assume* what the client-side HTML will be.

Comment: Please try and understand my question @David, My question is about jquery retrieving an image tag src from already rendered control (which contains the html with the <img> tag i retreave the src there) then the retrieved src to apply to another img tag src, In the same row of the repeater. As i said I know how to do that but not in a repeater for each row. i am not working with no server side code.

Comment: You may do well to also try to understand your question.  The ASP.NET markup you’re showing in the question *is* server-side code.  I really can’t state this any more clearly... JavaScript operates on the client-side HTML that gets sent to the browser.  So the very first step here would be for you to at least *look at* that HTML in the browser and *see what it is*.  We could make guesses and assumptions about that HTML, but if you can’t be bothered to even look at the output of you code then debugging is going to be pretty much impossible.

Comment: @David Sorry i think my level of understanding is not as high as yours, I am a self taught developer, but I do build standard working applications for a living. This is my last extreme way i could ask my predicament. That above is HTML code from a .aspx page not server side. So the controls do receive data from an sqldatasource.

Comment: Your understanding of "server side" vs. "client side" is entirely mistaken, I'm afraid.  When you view your page in a browser, open your browser's debugging tools and examine the HTML.  Or even just select "View Source" from the browser's menus.  The above markup is ***not*** the HTML used in the browser.  (If you *do* see these ASP.NET markup elements client-side then that would mean your ASP.NET setup isn't working at all.)  The code you're showing *outputs* HTML.  Again, and I can't specify this enough, *JavaScript only sees the HTML that this outputs, it doesn't run on the server*.

Comment: @David Ok got you thanks.

Comment: @David was you who down voted my question, You confuse me over terminology but the question is straight forward of what i want to achieve don't be over too high level man we all started at this level including you. Silly Expert.

Comment: After some time I have come back to look why I was down voted i still don't understand why. My question not be absolutely clear but for he who has knowledge of this area would have understood my dilemma, and not complicated me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe my mistake was limiting the criteria of my solution to jquery for my question. But the procedure i was trying to achieve was to to pull out the src of the img tag that was going to be present in the out putted html by the data-source in  Lable91 and use for a src for the adjucent img tag. This was meant to correspond for each row from the repeaters where the img src was pulled out. I ended up scraping the img tag and replaced it with a Label control and used the follow regex to achieve the same desired results:

```
    string input = Label91.Text;
    string pattern = @"</? *img[^>]*>";
    Regex rx = new Regex(pattern,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    foreach (Match m in rx.Matches(input))
    {
    string g = ( m.Value);
    Label17.Text = g;
    }
```

Thank you for down voting my question @whoever, If I was an expert then I would not be here asking a question.I wonder if experts do ask questions. Or may be show the right forum to none experts Like me.